# Concatenating different patterns of string

Tags: c++

I'm writing a function which concatenates different numbers of strings depending on their length.

Here is some c++ like pseudo code of what I'm currently doing:

```
string foo(size_t maxLength)
{
    string a, b, c, d, e, ret;

    //...assign them

    if(a.size() + b.size() + c.size() + d.size() + e.size() <= maxLength)
    {
        ret = a + b + c + d + e;
    }
    else if(a.size() + c.size() + d.size() + e.size() <= maxLength)
    {
        LOG << "B was removed.";
        ret = a + c + d + e;
    }
    else if(a.size() + b.size() + c.size() + d.size() <= maxLength)
    {
        LOG << "E was removed"l
        ret = a + b + c + d;
    }
    //... a large amount of code like the above

    return ret;    
}
```

Is there a nice way to clean this up?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you decide which one gets removed when it doesn't fit maxLength?

Comment: @quantumSoup: It's based on arbitrary rules that I can't control and which may change in the future

Comment: Also note that this looks a bit like the Knapsack problem, which is NP-complete (in other words, the solution will be inefficient)

Comment: @Jon And they are just random; there's no pattern that can be programatically detected or defined?

Comment: For what purpose your function is concatenating strings like this? What do you need to achieve with it?

Comment: You are not explaining what you are trying to do "concatenates different numbers of strings depending on their length", that sentence has many different interpretations all which give different answers. Be unambiguous when asking questions. You also do not specify in what order you are testing for subsets, or even declare that is in fact what you are doing.

Comment: @quantumSoup: It looks similar to the knapsack problem, but so far he has not indicated he requires the maximum subset... which would actually makes the problem easier.

Comment: it looks your designing an algorithm without an aim !!

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I'd convert it to array of strings. Then loop through your options and see which permutation actually fits your maxLength.

As quantumSoup commented - you did not mention your criteria for elimination, but once you have this defined, it is easy to iterate the options by eliminating the specific array indices, according to your priority criterion.

Answer (score 0):

If you were just looking to clean it up visually, something like:

```
    string a, b, c, d, e, ret, temp;

    //...assign them

    temp = a + b + c + d + e;
    if(temp.length <= maxLength) {
        LOG << "none removed";
        ret = temp;
    }

    temp = a + b + c + d;
    if(temp.length <= maxLength) {
        LOG << "e removed";
        ret = temp;
    }    

    temp = a + b + c + e;
    if(temp.length <= maxLength) {
        LOG << "d removed";
        ret = temp;
    }

    //... etc

    return ret;
```

As ysap mentioned, you can optimise it with loops if you have elimination criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If the order for omitting strings is arbitrary, I'd try to construct a list of some kind ordered by the priority.  Then I'd work my way through the list until I'd filled up the output buffer. If as you say the priorities are externally defined and arbitrary, you could probably drive it with constant table.